# Seeming inconsistency in scipy.integrate.quad operation under change of variable

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have an algorith that seeks to multiply two functions and integrate the result.  One is a small normal distribution around 1.0, with a small standard deviation of abouty .1; the other is also a normal, but much larger, with mean 100,000 and stdev 15,000.

The code looks like so:

```
def integrand(x, z, mu, sigma) :  
    # goal is to return return  f_x(x)*f_y(z/x)*1/abs(x)
#   return normal(x, mu, sigma) * normal(z/x, 100000, 15000)/abs(x) 
    return normal(z/x, mu, sigma) * normal(x, 100000, 15000)/abs(x) 

    pResult = quad(integrand, -10000000,10000000,
                       args=(_z, MU, SIGMA),
                       points = [1.0, 2.0, 100000.0],
                       epsabs = 1, epsrel = .01)
```

This is a formula for multiplying random variables, Z = XY.  It would seem that I could swap where the z/x goes in the integrand, but in trying to see which way runs faster (by commenting out one of the two return statements in integrand())  I was surprised to get different results (one is 114,221.4 and the other is 116,174.2).  Any idea why?

Also, when I cycle through a wide range of z values and plot P(z) vs z, the graphs look different,  One looks right (like a normal distribution - using the first return statement) and the other looks like a top-hat with soft corners.

The math for this algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution

Answer (score 0):

Scaling matters, as I noted in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49738870), and recommended to use `points` to help `quad` locate  relatively small features.

You rescale the function but keep the same interval of integration. Assuming the function essentially "fits" in the interval (the tails outside of the interval are negligible), the difference is due to the algorithm being able or unable to locate the small feature of the function (the narrow Gaussian) within the interval of integration. The more narrow is the function support, the more likely is `quad` to get integration wrong.

I also recommend putting accuracy as the top priority; speed comes after that. It's easy to write a function that returns "0" quickly.